# What is wrong in my syntax?

Tags: php, oracle

So I have this simple do_signup.php partial code:

```
<?php
$conn=oci_connect('system', 'user');
if(!$conn){
echo 'Can not connect';
}

$uname=$_POST['username'];
$pass=$_POST['password'];
$pstmt1="select * from admin where username='$uname'";
$stdi1=oci_parse($conn, $pstmt1);
oci_execute($stdi1);
oci_fetch($stdi1);
$numrow=oci_num_rows($stdi1);

if($numrow==0){
    $pstmt2="insert into admin(username,password) values('$uname', '$pass')";
    $stdi2=oci_parse($conn, $pstmt2);
    oci_execute($stdi2);

    oci_close($conn);
    header('Location: signup_success.php');
}else{
    oci_close($conn);
    header('Location: signup_fail.php');
}

?>
```

When my table is empty, I always get redirected to signup_fail.php. Again, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$stdi1=oci_parse($conn, $pstmt1);
```

Your variable name is : **$stdi1**

Then you execute : **$stdi**

replace `$stdi` with  `$stdi1` in `oci_execute($stdi);`

EDIT:
Look at the php manuel : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.oci-num-rows.php

you have to fetch the result in order to use the  `oci_num_rows` function to return the fetched row (select) and not the affected row like with DML query.

like:

```
oci_execute($stdi1); 
oci_fetch($stdi1);
$numrow=oci_num_rows($stdi1);
```

Comment: Another problem appeared. Earlier, I always get redirected to signup_success.php when I entered the same values. Now, I always get redirected to signup_fail.php when my table is empty.

Comment: change your test to    if ( ! $numrow > 0 )

Comment: Your condition is not different with mine.

Comment: Any possibilites that the function returns -1 or null ?

Comment: My admin table is empty, it must return null or 0 and accept new values, but i always get redirected to signup_fail.php

Comment: What if you replace the condition by `if( ! oci_fetch(stdi1) )` according to the manuel, oci_fetch returns FALSE when there are no more rows in the statement.  Or you can try the answer given by @Jerald

Answer (score 1):

First wrong:

```
$pstmt1="select * from admin where username='$uname'";//remove extra semicolon
```

Second Wrong:

`$pstmt2="insert into admin(username,password) values('$uname', '$pass')";`//remove extra semicolon and write your insert syntax in correct way

Comment: semicolon and insert syntax edited, but still something is wrong.

Comment: Entering existing values still redirect to signup_success.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
oci_define_by_name($stmt, 'NUMBER_OF_ROWS', $number_of_rows);
oci_execute($stmt);
oci_fetch($stmt);
echo $number_of_rows;
```

Comment: So he has to change `SELECT * FROM ...` by `SELECT count(1) NUMBER_OF_ROWS FROM ...`.